# Flutter snapshot.hasError is always false

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm pretty new to flutter. I can't understand why in my code I cannot trigger the snapshot.hasError property. Here is my code, it's basically the same as in the Flutter examples:

Inside the column builder:

```
...
RoundedButton(
        text: "SIGNUP",
        press: () {
          setState(() {
            _signupRequested = Auth().signup(_emailController.text,
                _passwordController.text, _usernameController.text);
          });
        },
      ),
...
```

The signup function:

```
class Auth extends BaseLogic {
  Future<bool> signup(String email, String password, String username) async {
    BasicResponse response = await AuthRepo().signup(email, password, username);
    if (response.success) {
      await this.setValue('signup_requested', 'y');
      return true;
    } else {
      throw Exception(response.reason!);
    }
  }
...
```

Future builder:

```
FutureBuilder<bool> buildFutureBuilder() {
    return FutureBuilder<bool>(
      future: _signupRequested,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          if (snapshot.data!) {
            return buildWait();
          } else {
            return buildColumn(null);
          }
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return buildColumn(snapshot.error.toString());
        }
        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }
```

If signup function throws the explicit exception or another exception (from the repo) the snapshot.hasError property is always false...

Comment: Did you check that  "throw Exception(response.reason!); " case is being called or not

Comment: Yes, both that exception and inner exceptions for repo are thrown and shown in the vscode console

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem, I was using setState inside the builder to initialize the variable, somehow removing it made it work